# Building custom RPM with required PHP version installation fails

Tags: php, rpm, specifications

I have created my application's `RPM` file and trying to install it on `CentOS 6.6`. My Application requires `PHP >= 5.4` which I mentioned as `Requires: php >= 5.4` in the `SPEC` file of `RPM`. But when I try to install the `RPM`, I get the following error

```
Error: Package: myApp-1.0-1.x86_64 (myapp)

           Requires: php >= 5.4
           Available: php-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
               php = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
```

The server where I am installing this does not have any PHP installed before.

```
[root@license /]# php --version
-bash: php: command not found
```

So I am not able to find the root cause. Can someone please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This just means that on CentOS 6 there is no php in version 5.4 or higher. Just version 5.3.3.

You either have to use CentOS 7. Or use SoftwareCollection:
https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/php55/

Comment: Hello msuchy, basically I know that there is no PHP but when I say Requires: php >= 5.4 in my Spec file, I expect that the RPM should install PHP 5.4 but instead I get that error message. How can I do avoid the error and get the PHP5.4 installed while executing RPM?

Comment: The packages are installed from repositories. Somebody have to put those packages there first. CentOS 6 was release in 2010 and since then it receive only binary compatible updates. It is very stable OS and does not change. On the other hand PHP 5.4 was released in 2012. So it is not (and will not be) present in CentOS 6 package repository. Just saying that you Requires: php >= 5.4 will not pull this package from the air.